# How to store steps taken daily and reset the app step count daily?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a step counter and I want to store the steps taken last day and reset the step count next day while still storing the previous data in another `textView`.

Here's my code:

```
public class StepsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    SensorManager sensorManager;
    TextView textView;
    boolean running=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_steps);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_steps);
        sensorManager  =(SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        running = true;
        Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
        if (countSensor != null) {
            sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Sensor not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        running = false;
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        if (running) {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(sensorEvent.values[0]));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }
}
```

Comment: do you need to persist just the previuos day or every day?

Comment: I want everyday

Comment: then i suggest you to store each value in a local db

Comment: And how do I reset the value daily, so it shows 0 after 12

Comment: I mean after 12am

Comment: you haven't necessarily to reset the counter, in the db you store the daily count, then you display to the user the absolute difference between the days

Comment: ok, thanks for your help